# Classes from module with different variables

Tags: python, class, import, module

It's very hard to express my question in words. Basicly I'v got the classes handle everything in ***base.py***:

```
x = 3
class object_one(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = x+3
class object_two(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = x**2
        self.y = object_one()
```

These are my basic objects. Now I need `object_one` and `object_two` several times doing the same but with different variables `x`:

***module_a.py***

```
from base import object_one, object_two    # with x = 7
```

***module_b.py***

```
from base import object_one, object_two    # with x = 13
```

But how do the *module_*.py* have to look like that I get

```
import module_a, module_b
print(module_a.object_one().x, module_a.object_two().y.x)   # Output:  49  49
print(module_b.object_one().x, module_b.object_two().y.x)   # Output: 169 169
```

Because there are more than two classes in *base.py* and more than two modules *a* and *b* I don't want to use class variables set in *modules_*.py* for each class.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What are you actually trying to achieve? This smells as though it would be a good way of creating very unmaintainable code.

Comment: *module_\*.py* are different **devices** (Lock-In amplifier, stage controller etc.). In *base.py* there are several containers (preferences, API, GUI, ...) for the different **models** of each device (e. g. Lock-In: Stanford Research, Signal Recovery, etc.) given in `x`.

Comment: why do you have x=3 at the top of base.py , would it not be better to just pass x as a parameter in object construction when you need it ?

Comment: Are you intending to write code that does different things depending on the value of x? The object-oriented approach would be to have derived/specialized classes which each implement the behaviour for a particular value of x. Then your product code that instantiates these specialized classes also gets the correct behaviour.

Comment: No, because this would make two things necessary:
1. I have to pass the same `x` to every single class of *base.py* separately. (That's why I try to avoid class variables)
2. In *module_\*.py* I need the classes and not instances of it.

Comment: @barny: No, the code do the same for all values of `x`. But its result depends on `x`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider passing x and ObjectOne as arguments:

```
class ObjectOne:
    def __init__(self, x):
    self.x = x

class ObjectTwo:
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.x = obj.x**2
        self.y = obj
```

Then module_a.py (and module_b.py) should contain:

```
x = 7 # in module_b.py x = 13
```

Then again, your main program:

```
import base, module_a, module_b

a1 = base.ObjectOne(module_a.x)
a2 = base.ObjectTwo(a1)

b1 = base.ObjectOne(module_b.x)
b2 = base.ObjectTwo(b1)

print(a1.x, a2.y.x)
print(b1.x, b2.y.x)
```

You didn't specified version, i assume from print() it's Python3, but in Python3 you don't need object in the class definition.

Comment: Unfortunately your approach with propagation of `x` is not applicable to my concrete problem. In realitiy just a part of `x` is stored in `object_one` and another part is need in `object_two`.

Answer (score 0):

I did it with class variables now. Unfortunately this requires the defintion of new child classes and the repeat of `x`.

***base.py***:

```
class object_one(object):
    x = 3
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = type(self).x + 3
class object_two(object):
    x = 3
    class_object_one = object_one
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = type(self).x**2
        self.y = type(self).class_object_one()
```

e. g. ***module_a.py***:

```
import base

class object_one(base.object_one):
    x = 7
class object_two(base.object_two):
    x = 7
    class_object_one = object_one
```

It's a lot of overhead for every *module_*.py* just for changing `x`.